# How can I date this carved wood sculpture?

Tags: europe, art, fashion

I found this beautiful wood-carved sculpture:

[image: sculpture]

It does look quite old and I wonder around what it was created. Also I'm interested which things to look out for, in order to determine the age and possibly spot newer imitations.

#### More images

[image: closeup]

[image: statue]

Comment: Where was it found? Are there any markings on the base?

Comment: @KillingTime It was found in an thrift shop in St. Gallen. There are no markings at the base, just bare wood.

Comment: Ask her if she'd like to go out for coffee.

Comment: interesting: the skin's is cracked, but the clothes are not. Repainted? Different paints or techniques?

Comment: @ClintEastwood: Thanks for your precious dating advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To date this sculpture, you could look at pictures and other sculptures and compare the style of clothing. Or take a book about medieval clothing and try to determine the period of the clothing this way. Probably a combination of these two approaches would be a good idea.

Edit: The determination of the clothing gives you a starting point for your research, a date after which the sculpture is done.

The headpiece looks to me like a [Hennin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hennin) which would put it roughly in the 15th century. Also the dress seems to fit in this period, compared for example with this painting from Hans Memling, Portrait of a young woman / bride from the second half of the 15th century.

But I am no expert in this area and would be very interested if somebody knew more details.
[image: Memling, Portrait of a young woman]

Comment: You can't base the age of artworks on the style of dress, you can only assume that it was created sometime **after** that point in time.

Comment: Well, yes and no. It gives a terminus post quem, a point AFTER which it is created, as you said. And that creates a starting point for the research, e.g. you could start looking for comparable sculptures from this date onwards.
Of course, it could be a historical work, done just some years ago. But I deem that rather unlikely. Comparison of the style, how the carving and painting is done should finally help in dating.

Comment: Begging your pardon here, but 1500-2017 is a pretty significant date range in which to search for comparable sculptures.  This one could easily be from 50 years ago.

Comment: I did not say it would be "totally easy and fast"? 500 years look rather short to me, usually I am more concerned with artwork that could be done theoretically anywhere in the range of -500 until today.
What would you suggest instead as a starting point?

Comment: the posture, the position of the hands and the form of the dress make it look more recent